# How to Configure Packer to Run 'sudo' to Provision Digital Ocean Image?

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean, packer

How do you configure a Packer recipe so that your provisioner can execute the sudo command on a Digital Ocean image?  I have the following recipe in which I'm trying to install Ansible on the remote host so that I can provision it using the Ansible playbook "site.yml" located on my local management host.  The problem is that the recipe fails because sudo cannot be found.  I'm not sure what account the Packer's provisioning commands are running as since there doesn't appear to be a way to specify the creation of a user account during the build phase with Digital Ocean.  But whatever account it is, packer can't find sudo because this unknown account's name isn't in the sudoers file.  How can I run my provisioners if there's nothing other than a password-less root account when the remote machine's image is built?

Thanks!

Packer recipe:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "do_api_token": "<my api token>"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "digitalocean",
            "api_token": "{{user `do_api_token`}}",
            "image": "debian-8-x64",
            "region": "sfo1",
            "size": "512mb"
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "sleep 30",
                "sudo apt-get update",
                "sudo apt-get install -y ansible"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "playbook_file": "site.yml",
            "inventory_file": "inventory.ini"
        }
    ]
}
```

Packer error:

```
digitalocean output will be in this color

digitalocean: Creating temporary ssh key for droplet...
digitalocean: Creating droplet...
digitalocean: Waiting for droplet to become active...
digitalocean: Waiting for SSH to become available...
digitalocean: Connected to SSH.
digitalocean: Provisioning with shell script: /var/folders/bm/d7bxd26n0md057x36jhbv7280000gn/T/packer-shell79618998.
digitalocean: /tmp/script_7943.sh: 3: /tmp/script_7943.sh: sudo: not found.     <= ERROR!!!
digitalocean: Destroying droplet...
digitalocean: Deleting temporary ssh key...
digitalocean' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 12.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> digitalocean: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 127

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that sudo is installed? According to the [Digital Ocean page on  Debian 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-debian-8),

> Debian 8 doesn't come with sudo installed, so let's install it with
>   apt-get.

The article goes on to detail instructions for creating a new user with sudo permissions which you may find helpful later on, but in the short term, have you just tried dropping sudo from your ansible code?